gpio.shutdown brings shutdown options window
I'm trying to use the gpio-shutdown overlay withe the following code pasted into config.txt
dtoverlay=gpio-shutdown,gpio_pin=15
gpio=23=op,dh

In my circuit, under normal operations GPIO 15 is high, and goes low when I have to shutdown the raspberry. Is isn't a momentary LOW, but constant LOW. The first problem I encountered is that the RPI reacts only when GPIO 15 goes high again, but it should react right after it going low. The second problem is that the RPI doesn't shut down, but a shutdown options windows is opened and nothing else happens.
I'm using Raspberry Pi Zero 2

Which Pi? What OS is installed (detail including version)?

Why do you believe that "... it [raspberry pi] should react right after it [GPIO15]  going low."?  Did you read that somewhere- are you guessing? - what?  And what is the function of the following line (gpio=23=op,dh)??

It's Zero 2. I installed Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm). Regarding my comment that it should react immediately - I'm describing how it should work in my application, ideally. I used this method: https://gist.github.com/lbussy/9e81cbcc617952f1250e353bd42e7775

DO NOT put detail in Comments - EDIT your Question

It works on all my Pi (except Pi5) BUT it works as documented i.e. with a momentary push button. The documentation actually says on pin change; if you want to use it design suitable circuitry to emulate a pin CHANGE.
The behaviour you describe is probably due to the new Pi5 shutdown process.

Thanks, I'm using Zero 2.

Regardless of what model you are using the functionality is the same. If you want something different  from the documented behaviour YOU have to do it yourself.
